# Fancybox with Cakephp not opening

Tags: fancybox, cakephp-2.3

I am trying to implement fancybox with cakephp 2.3. Is their any other method to do so. Because I am implementing traditional way. Issue is its not working above all its not showing any error..

I am using jquery-1.9.1 version & fancybox version is 2.1.5.

I tried .. .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.various').fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'fade',
        closeEffect : 'fade'
    });
});
</script>
```

and cake Link is like

```
 <?php echo $this->Html->link($enquiry['Enquiry']['name'], array('controller' => 'enquiries', 'action' => 'view', $enquiry['Enquiry']['id']), array('escape' => false, "class" => "various fancybox.ajax")); ?>
```

I am also using requesthandler as well of Cakephp

I am not getting any error in console but its not working as well.
I tried lower version of fancybox that is 1.3.4 that is working fine.

Comment: Get it working without the Cake helper first. This more of a javascript code problem so manually create the HTML for the link and tweak that link to get working. If it still doesn't work, post the link.  (but if a previous version of Fancybox works, then the newer Fancybox must require different HTML links)

Comment: as long as the html (link) has the class `various` it should work with the posted code. My concern would be what cakephp is actually rendering from this `"class" => "various fancybox.ajax"`